# Why does TypeScript add "prototype"?

Tags: typescript

My typescript code:

```
export class File {
    isOpenEnabled() {
        return false;
    }

    openClicked() {
        debugger;
    }
}

define([], function () {
    return {
        handler: new File()
    };
});
```

Is turned into:

```
define(["require", "exports"], function(require, exports) {
    var File = (function () {
        function File() {
        }
        File.prototype.isOpenEnabled = function () {
            return false;
        };

        File.prototype.openClicked = function () {
            debugger;
        };
        return File;
    })();
    exports.File = File;

    define([], function () {
        return {
            handler: new File()
        };
    });
});
```

Why the insertion of prototype?

thanks - dave

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Functions in javascript are objects.

For example:

```
function MyClass () {

  this.MyMethod= function () {};
}
```

Every time a new instance of `MyClass` is created, a new instance of `MyMethod` is also created.
A better approach is to add the function `MyMethod` to the prototype of `MyClass`:

```
MyClass.prototype.MyMethod = function(){};
```

In this way no matter how many instances of `MyClass` you create, only a single `MyMethod` will be created.

Back to your question I think that typescript is doing exactly this kind of optimization for the methods that you defined in your `File` class.

Comment: So it creates MyClass.prototype once and it is then assigned to all instances of the MyClass object? Thanks - dave

Answer (score 1):

There are two reason:

- Memory optimization (already mentioned by Alberto)
- Prototypical Inheritance

The second reason as well as the first is well covered in : http://javascript.crockford.com/inheritance.html